# What's the difference between subprocess Popen and call (how can I use them)?

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I want to call an external program from Python. I have used both `Popen()` and `call()` to do that.

What's the difference between the two?

My specific goal is to run the following command from Python. I am not sure how redirects work.

```
./my_script.sh > output
```

I read [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) and it says that `call()` is a convenience function or a shortcut function. Do we lose any power by using `call()` instead of `Popen()`?

Comment: What part of the documentation confused you?  The definition of `call()` seems to be very clear.  Can you provide a quote or a link so we know what to focus on in an answer?

Answer (score 321, accepted):

There are two ways to do the redirect. Both apply to either `subprocess.Popen` or `subprocess.call`.

1. Set the keyword argument `shell = True` or `executable = /path/to/the/shell` and specify the command just as you have it there.
2. Since you're just redirecting the output to a file, set the keyword argument

   ```
   stdout = an_open_writeable_file_object
   ```

   where the object points to the `output` file.

[`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) is more general than [`subprocess.call`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call).

`Popen` doesn't block, allowing you to interact with the process while it's running, or continue with other things in your Python program. The call to `Popen` returns a `Popen` object.

`call` *does* block. While it supports all the same arguments as the `Popen` constructor, so you can still set the process' output, environmental variables, etc., your script waits for the program to complete, and `call` returns a code representing the process' exit status.

```
returncode = call(*args, **kwargs)
```

is basically the same as calling

```
returncode = Popen(*args, **kwargs).wait()
```

`call` is just a convenience function. It's implementation in CPython is in [subprocess.py](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e0df7db13d55/Lib/subprocess.py#l459):

```
def call(*popenargs, timeout=None, **kwargs):
    """Run command with arguments.  Wait for command to complete or
    timeout, then return the returncode attribute.

    The arguments are the same as for the Popen constructor.  Example:

    retcode = call(["ls", "-l"])
    """
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
        try:
            return p.wait(timeout=timeout)
        except:
            p.kill()
            p.wait()
            raise
```

As you can see, it's a thin wrapper around `Popen`.

Comment: Basically Popen and call are  asynchronous and Synchronous functions respectively  used  run Linux commands.

Comment: What's the advantage of using popen? Wouldn't it be safe to wait till the called program finishes first?

Comment: @Tom Often not. What if you want to read some output, then send more input to the program, read more output that results from that input, repeat?

Comment: @user3016020 I assume this also applies to Windows commands?  Right?

Comment: @user3016020 I do not get your phrase, could you elaborate? used run Linux commands..

Comment: I thought that popen has an iterable as argument whereas call a string.

Answer (score 61):

The other answer is very complete, but here is a rule of thumb:

- `call` is blocking:

  ```
  call('notepad.exe')
  print('hello')  # only executed when notepad is closed
  ```
- `Popen` is non-blocking:

  ```
  Popen('notepad.exe')
  print('hello')  # immediately executed
  ```

Comment: call seems to be non-blocking with option shell=True