# Live output status from subprocess command Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, subprocess

I'm writing a script to get netstat status using subprocess.check_output.

```
cmd = 'netstat -nlpt'

result = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True, timeout=1800)
print(result.decode('utf-8'))
```

The above is running perfectly. Is there any way to get the live-streaming output. I have heard **poll()** function does this job. In [live output from subprocess command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421757/live-output-from-subprocess-command) they are using **popen** but i'm using **check_output** please some one help me on this issue. Thank you!

Comment: Actually no, they are using Popen and here i'm using check_output

Comment: You can't using `check_output`.

Comment: *Why* do you use ``check_output`` when you want life output instead?

Comment: Please do not edit your question in a way that changes its topic. This has invalidated previous answers.

Comment: Sorry for that i will ask a new question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40766307/13552470) answer:

> The difference between `check_output` and `Popen` is that, while `popen` is a non-blocking function (meaning you can continue the execution of the program without waiting the call to finish), `check_output` is blocking.

Meaning if you are using `subprocess.check_output()`, you cannot have a live output.

Try switching to `Popen()`.