# Is it possible to run ubuntu terminal commands using DJango

Tags: python, django, hadoop, hbase, hdfs

I am designing a simple website using DJango and my database is HBase. In some Part I need to save some files on HDFS, for example video file, and have it's URI. But my problem is I couldn't find any API for accessing HDFS through DJango so I decided to use ubuntu terminal command to upload and download data on HDFS. Now I want to know is there any way to run terminal command using Django or any other way to access HDFS API through Django?

Answer (score 0):

have django make a call to a subprocess like the one below.  each string in the command should be a string in a list.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to search for Django implemented libraries, Django is written in python and python is providing libraries for it.

An alternative solution

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['python', 'manage.py', 'runserver'])
```

you can excecute shell commands using subprocess.Popen also. 
The difference between subprocess Popen and call and how to use them is described here [What's the difference between subprocess Popen and call (how can I use them)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681715/whats-the-difference-between-subprocess-popen-and-call-how-can-i-use-them)