# Handling interactive shells with Python subprocess

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell, subprocess, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to run multiple instances of a console-based game (dungeon crawl stone soup -- for research purposes naturally) using a multiprocessing pool to evaluate each run.

In the past when I've used a pool to evaluate similar code (genetic algorithms), I've used `subprocess.call` to split off each process.  However, with dcss being quite interactive having a shared subshell seems to be problematic.

I have the code I normally use for this kind of thing, with crawl replacing other applications I've thrown a GA at.  Is there a better way to handle highly-interactive shells than this?  I'd considered kicking off a screen for each instance, but thought there was a cleaner way.  My understanding was that `shell=True` should be spawning a sub-shell, but I guess I it is spawning one in a way that is shared between each call.

I should mention I have a bot running the game, so I don't want any actual interaction from the user's end to occur.

```
# Kick off the GA execution
pool_args = zip(trial_ids,run_types,self.__population)
pool.map(self._GAExecute, pool_args)

---

# called by pool.map 
def _GAExecute(self,pool_args):
  trial_id       = pool_args[0]
  run_type       = pool_args[1]
  genome         = pool_args[2]
  self._RunSimulation(trial_id)

# Call the actual binary
def _RunSimulation(self, trial_id):
  command = "./%s" % self.__crawl_binary
  name    = "-name %s" % trial_id
  rc      = "-rc %s" % os.path.join(self.__output_dir,'qw-%s'%trial_id,"qw -%s.rc"%trial_id)
  seed    = "-seed %d" % self.__seed
  cdir    = "-dir %s" % os.path.join(self.__output_dir,'qw-%s'%trial_id)

  shell_command = "%s %s %s %s %s" % (command,name,rc,seed,cdir)
  call(shell_command, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed associate stdin and stdout to files, as in the answer from @napuzba:

```
fout = open('stdout.txt','w')
ferr = open('stderr.txt','w')
subprocess.call(cmd, stdout=fout, stderr=ferr)
```

Another option would be to use [Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) instead of [call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call). The difference is that call waits for completion (is blocking) while Popen is not, see [What's the difference between subprocess Popen and call (how can I use them)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681715/whats-the-difference-between-subprocess-popen-and-call-how-can-i-use-them)

Using Popen, you can then keep stdout and stderr inside your object, and then use them later, without having to rely on a file:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p.wait()
stderr = p.stderr.read()
stdout = p.stdout.read()
```

Another potential advantage of this method is that you could run multiple instances of Popen without waiting for completion instead of having a thread pool:

```
processes=[
  subprocess.Popen(cmd1,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE),
  subprocess.Popen(cmd2,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE),
  subprocess.Popen(cmd3,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
]

for p in processes:
  if p.poll():
     # process completed
  else:
     # no completion yet
```

On a side note, you should [avoid](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) `shell=True` if you can, and if you do not use it Popen expects a list as a command instead of a string. Do not generate this list manually, but use [shlex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html) which will take care of all corner cases for you, eg.:

```
Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: That is helpful, but I'm pretty sure I need the thread pool to be blocking.  It is running in a GA, so evaluation of all population members must complete before the next iteration of the controlling loop is called.

Comment: It is/can be blocking thanks to the `poll()` in the for loop. The interest of this solution is that you do not actually need to manage threads/threadpool yourself to start runs of subprocesses.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the standard input, standard output and standard error with unique file handles for each call:

```
import subprocess
cmd  = ""
fout = open('stdout.txt','w')
fin  = open('stdin.txt','r')
ferr = open('stderr.txt','w')
subprocess.call(cmd, stdout=fout , stdin = fin , stderr=ferr )
```

Comment: Would I actually be able to use that to capture a ttyrec?

Comment: Well, I am not familiar with ttyrec. However, You can supply the input from `fin` which can be file object or any file-like object.

Comment: If you work in linux - You can try using /dev/tty* files

Comment: Do I need to close the handles or will subprocess handle that?