# Python Script To Run Bash command

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x

I'm trying to get a script to run on Bash to transfer files from my local machine to a remote computer on my network. The bash command is
:

`scp \local\path\ user@remoteip:\path\to\copy\onremote`

This has worked alright so far, so I thought I'd automate it using a python script.
This is what I came up with:

```
import subprocess
direct = input("Enter path to directory: ")
send = "scp " + direct + " user@remoteip:\path\to\copy\onremote"
subprocess.Popen(send)
```

For some reason, It's not working, any ideas?

Comment: first thing I notice is you're not putting any space so the command after the string concat would be `scp\local\path\user@remoteip:\path\to\copy\onremote`

Comment: sorry, that's there, let me correct it.

Comment: What is the value of 'send' debugger shows? It seems to me that there are no spaces before and after 'direct'.

Comment: also I would use `subprocess.call` or `subprocess.check_call`

Comment: the value is: file not found @AlexanderChingarev

Comment: @aws_apprentice thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that Popen() expects a list. So the solution is to split the string on its spaces, `formatted = send.split(" ")`. As per the questions around using Popen() or call(), here is an excellent answer detailing the differences.[What's the difference between subprocess Popen and call (how can I use them)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681715/whats-the-difference-between-subprocess-popen-and-call-how-can-i-use-them)

Here is something that works for me, using subprocess call().

```
from subprocess import call
direct = input("Enter path to directory: ")
send = "scp" + direct + " user@remoteip:\path\to\copy\onremote"
formatted = send.split(" ")
call([formatted])
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working still... let me add the error to the question

Comment: Oh! my bad. I use call() wrong. All characters separated by a space needs to be its own list entity, I'll update my answer

Comment: Thank you! It seems my problem, and formerly yours, was splitting the string! Good Day!

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended that you pass in a list of arguments to the
`subprocess.Popen(["scp", "-r", "path", ...])`.

However, if you still want to pass in a whole string, pass an optional shell parameter like
`subprocess.Popen(send, shell=True)`.

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't the problem for me