# EOFError when starting with subproccess

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, eoferror

When i start my python3 script with subproccess from an other script i get the following error:

```
Select the keyword preset you want to use:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 9, in <module>
    keywordselect=input("Select the keyword preset you want to use:")
EOFError
```

But when i start the script normally with python3 generate.py it works totally fine with no error.

script1:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["python3", "test2.py"])
```

script2:

```
print("Keyword")
print("1. Preset1")
print("2. Preset2")
print("3. Preset3")
print("4. Preset4")
print("You can edit the presets in /presets/keywords/.")
selecting = 1
while selecting == 1:
    keywordselect=input("Select the keyword preset you want to use:")
    if keywordselect == "1":
        print("You selected keyword preset 1.")
        selectedkeywordlist = "presets/keywords/preset1.txt"
    elif keywordselect == "2":
        print("You selected keyword preset 2.")
        selectedkeywordlist = "presets/keywords/preset2.txt"
    elif keywordselect == "3":
        print("You selected keyword preset 3.")
        selectedkeywordlist = "presets/keywords/preset3.txt"
    elif keywordselect == "4":
        print("You selected keyword preset 4.")
        selectedkeywordlist = "presets/keywords/preset4.txt"
    else:
        print("You didn't select a valid option, please try again.")
```

Comment: can you try `p = subprocess.call(["python3", generatefile])` ? you should show a [mcve] of your script1.

Comment: Your second script expects to read from `stdin` on `input("Select the keyword preset you want to use:")` But you are not providing any for the invoked subprocess as far as I can see

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre 
python3 pre-generate.py 
  File "generate.py", line 272
    
                                                                ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: @FlyingTeller i want the user to  type 1 2 3 or 4 in the subproccess

Comment: you probably redirected stdin earlier. Show a [mcve] of the first script

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre just the code above reproduces the problem for me
`import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["python3", "generate.py"])`

Comment: please [edit] your question to reflect that. Because it seems very hard to reproduce this issue

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre i edited it with exactly what i run and "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `subprocess.Popen` which is a by default non blocking, piece of code, hence You program cursor moves rather than waiting for the input from the user. But what you need is a code which is blocking your program cursor. `subprocess.call` exactly does it. It would be waiting for the other command to execute completely.

You need to use `subprocess.call` to solve your problem. Just change your script2 file with this

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.call(["python", "abca.py"])
```

You can read more about the difference between `subprocess.Popen` and `subprocess.call` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681715/whats-the-difference-between-subprocess-popen-and-call-how-can-i-use-them). Which describes when to use which command and the difference between them

Comment: my first comment suggested that, and OP commented back that it had the same effect.

Comment: I could replicate the issue. And when I used `subprocess.call`  it got solved

Comment: Hahaha. Seems like you did the same mistake as I did. You were trying to execute it from IDE. Now while executing it from terminal it got replicated. :P

Comment: Hahaha my mistake was trying to execute it in my head. Actually I thought that there was more than this in op first script. Let's see if you get acceptance.

Comment: the actual explanation is: the first script exits while the other script is running, breaking the input pipe.

Comment: Yes that would be the right explanation. I was not able to find the appropriate words. Why don't you edit the answer and put the right words?

Answer (score 0):

You have to redirect `stdin` and `stdout` with the call of `script2.py`, can use [subporcess.PIPE](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.PIPE) for that:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["python3", "test2.py"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```