# How allocate memory limit to python thread?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

How do we allocate memory limit to a python thread?

How does one use the threading and subprocess module to limit memory on that process? When I start threads ala the first answer here: [How to use threading in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2846653/8926905), the bash processes run sequentially instead of in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

For the last bit of that question, if you want them to run sequentially, i think you can use [Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor)

and use .wait()

I did something like this in a recent code

```
    script='/some/script.exe'
    my_args = [
        "--endpoint",endpoint,
        "--userid", userid,
        "--password", password,
        ....
    ]

    #1. Run the command that gets docs from Docusign Retrieve
    #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681715/whats-the-difference-between-subprocess-popen-and-call-how-can-i-use-them
    subprocess.Popen([script] + my_args).wait()
```

As you can see, I decided to use Popen here because from [What's the difference between subprocess Popen and call (how can I use them)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681715/whats-the-difference-between-subprocess-popen-and-call-how-can-i-use-them) I saw that it was synchronous (call is non-blocking analogue)