# How is it possible to wait/detect until the application is ready ("start-work" complete)

Tags: python, wait, popen, ready

I will in python start a application and wait until the application is **READY** (therefore I will **NOT** wait until the application is finished). It is a general question by me, therefore is it irrelevant from which application we speak here. In my case is it a "big" application" (by dSPACE ==> AurelionManager ==> [Product link to dSPACE-Homepage](https://www.dspace.com/de/gmb/home/products/sw/experimentandvisualization/aurelion_sensor-realistic_sim.cfm)) which need ca. 10 seconds or longer until the "loading status" of the application have reached 100% and the application is "usable" (by GUI or e.g. automatisized over python by using of web-services)

Therefore I need, like here described...
[Stackoverflow: whats-the-difference-between-subprocess-popen-and-call-how-can-i-use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681715/whats-the-difference-between-subprocess-popen-and-call-how-can-i-use-them#:%7E:text=Popen%20is%20more%20general%20than,Popen%20returns%20a%20Popen%20object.)
...e.g. ...

```
Popen('notepad.exe')
```

...so that I start the application by python and I have in general a none blocking behavior, but after this I should have any *"construct"/code* which wait so long until the *loading work* (of the application) is finished (therefore the application is from OS point of view *complete loaded and therefore the application is "ready"*) before I go on with "other work" in the python-world which try to communicate (in my case by web-services) with the even (by `Popen`) started application

Have anybody here a idea how I can reach this? Many thanks already now for the help :-)

Comment: Usually, big applications aren't loaded in memory completely but on demand, similar to a memory mapped file plus separate dynamic libraries and data files. Therefore it is complicated to find a definition of "loaded" or "ready" which can be measured without knowing the application in detail.

Answer (score 0):

I did contact the dSPACE-guys, in my case is the solution for waiting until the application is really simple ("BruceForce")

Try in a loop to send periodic a web-request (which try to "read" anything from the application) so long this produce a exception (exeption is of course catched of course) because the application is NOT "ready" go on with the loop. In other case (web-request work because application is "ready") break the loop (then can you send any web-request to the application)

I think that is at each application the solution (**pseudocode**):

```
import subprocess
import time

# Start your application (non-blocking):
subprocess.Popen('YourApplication.exe')

TIME_OUT = 5

# Now wait until application is ready or until timout happen:
timeout_time = time.time() + TIME_OUT 
while True:
    try:
        <Try over the automation-interface to communicate with the application>
        # This is only reached at success (no exception above):
        break
    except:
        pass
    # At timeout create exception:
    if time.time() > timeout_time:
        raise Exception("Timeout")

# When this here is reached so is the application ready:
<communicate with the automation-interface with the application>
<communicate with the automation-interface with the application>
...
```